# Jorani / presence.php - Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php

After installing, we found an error. How to solve it?

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
>
> Filename: hr/presence.php
>
> Line Number: 268

```
<?php foreach ($summary as $key => $value) { ?>
```

Comment: What is `$summary`? Can you do `print_r($summary);`?

Comment: So you are talking about Jorani, the leave management software. You need to provide more details. What is the version of Jorani? Is it a fresh install or an update? If it is an update, what is the previous version?

Answer (score 0):

Your $summary variable is probably null or not an array.
You could wrap the loop in an if condition and check whether its a valid array before traversing.

```
if(is_array($summary)) {
    foreach(...
}
```

Comment: `<?php foreach ($summary as $key => $value) { ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $key; ?></td>
<td><?php echo round(((float) $value[1] - (float) $value[0]), 3, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN); ?></td>
<td><?php if ($value[2] == '') { echo ((float) $value[0]); } else { echo '-'; } ?></td>
<td><?php if ($value[2] == '') { echo ((float) $value[1]); } else { echo '-'; } ?></td>
<td><?php echo $value[2]; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>`

Answer (score 0):

This error appears when the employee has no contract. So you can solve this error by editing the employee causing the error (from HR, list of employees: right click on the employee and choose edit into the context menu) and affecting him a contract.

If you don't have any contract, please start to create a contract from HR menu, list of contracts.

You can get help by joining the Google group of Jorani users: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jorani